# overwrite gorm methods in Domain using metaclass

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a Domain class called User.
When running test I wanted to redefine the get method of the User class by doing the following

> User.metaClass.static.get = {Long id -> [username:"joe", id:id]}

But applying the above does not seem to have an impact when I call

> User.get(2)

Can I use metaClass in the static Domain GORM methods like get() or list() to change their behavior ?
Thanks

Here it is my testCase:

> @Test
>
> void testMe(){
>
> ```
>   User.metaClass.static.get = { id -> [username:"joe", id:id]}
>
>   def user  = User.get(3)
>
>   assert user.username == "joe"
> ```
>
> }

and I get an NPE Cannot get property 'username' on null object

I can actually do it using groovy MockFor

> ```
>   def mockControl = new MockFor(User.class)
>
>   mockControl.demand.get {id -> return [username:"joe"]}
>
>   mockControl.use {
>
>       def user = User.get(3)
>
>       assert user.username == "joe"
>   }
> ```

Comment: Any reason you do not use available mocking apis?

Comment: @dmahapatro What mocking apis are you referring to?

Comment: `@Mock` is used for domain classes. Are you specifically trying to test `User.get` works as expected?

Comment: This is in an integration test. I tried actually to put the Mock annotation but I would get "Annotation @grails.test.mixin.Mock is not allowed on element METHOD"

Comment: I'm assuming the real test is bit more complex.   If you bypass the GORM database integration... what are you testing?  Integration tests don't allow Mock because you're supposed to be adding things to the DB during these tests.

Comment: Correct, I am trying to test a mothod in a servive, which has dependency among other things on the User, which I want to have control on (mock), because I want to take it out of the equation. What you are saying is that since I am using integration test, I should just put a User intance in the the database, so it can be picked up on the test.

Answer (score 0):

Don't type the closure parameter. If you were to use that method as you've written it you'd need to call `User.get(2L)`, otherwise you're passing an Integer and the signature doesn't match. It should work if you define `get` as

```
User.metaClass.static.get = { id -> [username:"joe", id:id]}
```

Comment: It makes sense what you are saying because I had run into that type of issue before, but in this case I am running still on the same problem

Comment: So, if I do {Long id ->} and then call User.get(2L) as you suggested, that works. Why is it that {def id -> } does not work.

Comment: Note, in older versions of Grails, the GORM methods like "get" were dynamically created using methodMissing.  In newer versions, most of them (except for dynamicFinders) are compiled in using AST Transforms.  The reason your "Long" works, is probably because you're not actually overriding or using the GORM method, just the one you added.

Comment: So methods added by AST transformation, are not part of "metaClass life cycle" ?

Comment: No, methods added by AST transforms are available to be overridden, those added dynamically by GORM are NOT.  I'm suggesting that if you're using an older version of Grails, you may not be able to do what you want.   I still suggest just populating your DB during integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following annotation to your test

`@Mock([User])`

Then you could do something like this:

`def userControl = mockFor(User)`
`userControl.demand.static.get() {Long id -> return null}`

Comment: Since it is integration test, the @Mock annotation does not seem to work